# How get facet input checkbox field into label

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I am using [facets module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets). The current markup of the facets:

```
<li class="facet-item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facets-checkbox">
    <label for="contactvoorkeur-email">E-mail
        <span class="facet-count">(2)</span>
    </label>
    <a href="#">E-mail
        <span class="facet-count">(2)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

How do I get the facet input checkbox field into the label? So I get:

```
<li class="facet-item">
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description">Check this custom checkbox</span>
</label>
    <a href="#">E-mail
        <span class="facet-count">(2)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Is this possible?